# Angular поиск без привязки к регистру

Tags: angularjs, поиск

Сейчас поиск работает так:

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.items = [  
          -- данные --
      ];
      $scope.search = function(o, i, a) {
      if (!$scope.searchPlayers) return true;
      var filter = $scope.searchPlayers.split(' ');
      var keys = Object.keys(o);
      return filter.every(function(f) {
        return keys.some(function(key) {
          return !key.startsWith('$$') && (this[key] + '').indexOf(f) > -1;
        }, o);
      });
    };
  });
</script>
```

Но сейчас поиск регистрозависимый, как это исправить?

Comment: а что если предварительно приводить к одному регистру?

Comment: Метод toLowerCase() возвращает значение строки, на которой он был вызван, преобразованное в нижний регистр.

Comment: я это понимаю) просто в ангуляре не особо пока шарю, понять не могу как привести к одному регистру